# How can I correct referencing error 1824 in MySQL Workbench?

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

```
USE UNIVERSITY;

CREATE TABLE STUDENT (
Fname           VARCHAR(15)     NOT NULL,
Lname           VARCHAR(15)     NOT NULL,
Student_ID      CHAR(9)         NOT NULL,
Bdate           DATE,
Address         VARCHAR(50),
Sex             CHAR,
Mobile          INT             NOT NULL,
Course_ID       INT(15)         NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (Student_ID),
FOREIGN KEY (Course_ID) REFERENCES COURSE(Course_ID)
);

CREATE TABLE COURSE (
Cname     VARCHAR(25)    NOT NULL,
Course_ID   INT(15)    NOT NULL,
Start_date  DATE,
End_date   DATE,
Module_ID  CHAR(9)       NOT NULL,
UNIQUE (Cname),
primary key (Course_ID),
foreign key (Module_ID) REFERENCES MODULE(Module_ID)
);

CREATE TABLE MODULE (
Module_ID CHAR(15)  NOT NULL,
HE_Level INT        NOT NULL,
Course_ID CHAR(9)   NOT NULL,
Lecturer_ID CHAR(9) NOT NULL,
primary key(Module_ID),
foreign key(Course_ID) REFERENCES COURSE(Course_ID),
foreign key(Lecturer_ID) references LECTURER(Lecture_ID)
);

CREATE TABLE LECTURER (
Fname           VARCHAR(15)     NOT NULL,
Lname           VARCHAR(15)     NOT NULL,
Lecturer_ID     CHAR(9)         NOT NULL,
Bdate           DATE,
Address         VARCHAR(50),
Sex             CHAR,
Mobile          INT             NOT NULL,
Module_ID       CHAR(9)         NOT NULL,
primary key(Lecturer_ID),
foreign key(Module_ID) references MODULE(Module_ID)
);
```

i get an error 1824 "failed to open referenced table course.

Comment: Your schema does not look good. You have self-referencing tables, which do not seem to make sense. For example, does a course belong to a module, or a module belongs to a course?

Comment: every table that is referencd must exist, s order them correctly

Comment: that said Module and lecturer are referencing another that is so not possible

Comment: Personally, I wouldn't use the student's student number as the referential key, but maybe that's just me.

Comment: @gmb module table belongs to the course table it’s a dependent